# On the grade of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, noetherian

I need to prove the following statment (actually a special case of it).

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $R$-module and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Then
>   $\operatorname{grade}(I,M)\geq 2$ if and only if the homomorphism $M\rightarrow$Hom$_R(I,M)$ given by $m\mapsto(i\mapsto im)$ is an isomorphism.

This is Exercise 1.2.24 in Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*.

Comment: What is $\mathrm{grade}(I,M)$?

Comment: It's the length of a maximal regular sequence of $M$ contained in $I$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the long exact sequence in Ext from the ses $$ 0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0,$$
leading to
$$ 0 \to \hom(R/I, M) \to \hom(R, M) \to\hom(I,M) \to \mathrm{Ext}^1(R/I, M) \to 0,$$
because $R$ is projective. It is known that depth (or grade) can be measured in terms of Exts, and in particular that it is at least 2 if the two ends of the sequence vanish. But this is equivalent to the condition that $\hom(R, M) \to \hom(I,M)$ be an isomorphism.