# Is the dual of an integral ideal isomorphic to a fractional ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a one-dimensional domain and $I \subset R$ an integral ideal. Is its dual module $I^\vee = \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,R)$ isomorphic to a fractional ideal of $R$?

If $I$ is invertible, then we have $I^\vee \cong I^{-1}$ which is a fractional ideal. But what if $I$ is not invertible?

I would like to see an easy counter-example with a $R$ one-dimensional but not Dedekind! This comes down to see such a homomorphism which is not given by multiplication with an element of $\operatorname{Quot}(R)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $f\in I^\vee$, then $f(a)=xa$ for all $a\in I$, and some $x$ in the field of fractions of $R$. Obviously $x\in I^{-1}$. The correspondence $f\mapsto x$ is an isomorphism between $I^\vee$ and $I^{-1}$ for every integral domain $R$ and any non-zero ideal $I$.

Comment: @user26857 And how do you prove that every such $f \in I^\vee$ is given by the multiplication with an element of the field of fractions of $R$?

Comment: $f(ab)=af(b)=bf(a)$ for all $a,b\in I$.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/822728/121097

Comment: @user26857 Ah, thats neat, thank you!